# Understanding a proof exercise Evans PDE mean value formula

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

I am trying to understand a solution to exercise 2.5 (3) in Evans' PDE pag 85-86, which tates the following: [image] 
[image]

The part in the Oval is the one I have trouble understanding. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $f$ is bounded, which is archived e.g. by $f\in C_c(B(0,r))$, say $|f|\leq K$.
For the volume of the n-dimensional ball with radius $\epsilon$, you have:
$$
|B(0,\epsilon)|=\alpha(n)\epsilon^n
$$
where $n$ is the dimension we are working in and $|\;|$ denotes the lebesgue measure.
So now you can estimate the integral:
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n-2}}\int_{B(0, \epsilon)}fdy\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n-2}} K |B(0,\epsilon)|=\alpha(n)K\frac{\epsilon^n}{\epsilon^{n-2}}=C\epsilon^2
$$

Comment: yes, however, I have no way of saying that $f$ is bonded in the ball. Do I just Assume it?

Comment: As for this exercise, it is not further specified at all what $f$ is. However, in the proof for existence of a solution for Poissons equation, Evans assumes $f\in C_c^2$.

Comment: @Alfdav it says to modify the proof of the mean value formula where it gives the condition on f.

Comment: @DaveNine I am not seeing that in the text. The mean value formula that are given in page 25-26 are for the laplace equation, therefore no $f$